# How to answer YES automatically with a cryptsetup luksFormat command?

Tags: command-line, scripting, luks, cryptsetup

How to run cryptsetup luksFormat non-interactively

When LUKS formatting a partition, I recieve the message

```
# cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/sdb irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
```

Followed by `Enter passphrase:`.

**How can I automatically answer `YES` to the question "Are you sure ?**

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make use of the `--batch-mode, -q` option of `cryptsetup` to skip the question.

```
$ cryptsetup -q luksFormat /dev/sdb
```

This option also disables password verification, so one should use it with care or in an automated environment